# AngularJS - $emit only works within it's current scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created 2 directives: Parent and Child. Trying to get them to talk to one another. It seems if they both have a scope they don't receive the events. This doesn't seem correct according to the documentation which `$emit` states: `Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$on listeners.`

So surely that should bubble up through scopes?

http://plnkr.co/edit/WNqN4XZKaLAvBEtSyERA?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The problem is with you *parent/child* assumption:

- **Parent** is only a parent element of **Child** but not a parent scope.
- Actually they are **sibling scopes**, both children of the **$rootScope** (*$id: 002*) in this case.

#### Why??

- Due to [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7), `Isolate scope is now available only to the isolate directive that requested it and its template`.
- It means that **parent directive contents** (which included the child directive) are still linked to the outer scope.
- So the **child directive** creates isolated scope which is a child of the outer scope.
- Neither **$emit** nor **$broadcast** would work with sibling scopes.

[image]

---

#### Solution:

here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EfKJthkQLitWnF2srykM?p=preview

You can create the child directive as a template of the parent directive, because template directives do get the directive's scope as mentioned above.

```
.directive('parent', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    template:'<child name="Jimmy"></child>',
```

---

#### do you really need the event bus?

Another solution would be to create a controller on the parent directive and to require it in child directives.

```
.directive('parent', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    controller: function(){
      this.hungry = function(message){
        // something
      }
    }
```

**child directive:**

```
.directive('child', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    require: "^parent",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {

       parentCtrl.hungry("I'm hungry!")
```

Comment: Damn, that's quite unexpected. In my mind I was thinking of events like DOM events where they bubble up the DOM. I can imagine many people fall for this trap. The reason I thought events were the solution is because The child doesn't require the parent to function, I wanted to emit events for other directives to listen if they want to know the result of a calculation as they require the child to function for what he knows. I'm guessing I need to pass in data from the outside, alter it and watch inside the parent directive for the change. Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: You can also use `require: "?^parent"` to optionally require a parent directive's controller. From [$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile): *Attempt to locate the required controller by searching the element's parents or pass null to the link fn if not found.*

Answer (score 1):

In your example both directives have isolated scopes from the same parent scope, so they do not have parent/child relationship.

To get it work as you expected you may specify `scope: true` instead of `scope: {...}`. In this case the scope of child directive will be really child scope of parent directive's scope.

[see the plucker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t08nKKHbF8RTbeTM12Jl?p=preview)