# AngularJS : ng-transclude in directive and sending events to parent

Tags: angularjs, transclusion

I have custom directives like this:

```
<fold fold-name="Musique et sons">
    <sound-button height=60  song-name="Why Make..."></sound-button>
</fold>
```

fold directive has such template:

```
<button class="fold" ng-click="showMe = !showMe">{{foldName}} ({{nb}})</button>
<div class="fold" ng-transclude ng-show="showMe"></div>
```

In the sound-button controller, I have to do this:

```
$scope.$parent.$$prevSibling.$emit('foldstop')
```

If I want the  controller to receive the event:

```
      $scope.$on 'foldplay', (sender, evt) ->
```

What's happening:
     
         
creates 3 scopes :

```
 <fold> Scope
 <ng-transclude scope> which has no model, thus no controller.
      <sound-button scope>
```

In sound-button directive, $scope.$emit would hit the ng-transclude scope which is a sibling of the scope I want to hit.

So I'm using $scope.$parent.$prevSibling to hit the right controller.
It works, but is there a better way ?

Thanks !

Comment: I am a little bit confused. If you want to do stuff inside fold. You can create a controller in fold and call it from sound-button when you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `require` if your directives are related.

```
app.directive('soundButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        songName: '@'
      },
      require:"^fold", 
      link : function (scope,element,attrs,foldController){//inject fold controller 
           foldController.callFold("message"); //use the controller to communicate
      }
    };
});

app.directive('fold', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        foldName: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: 'fold.html',
      transclude:true,

      controller:function(){ //declare the controller to be used by child directives.
          this.callFold = function (message){
            alert(message);
          }
      }
    };
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pYNGa2y8UMeqdKa41Hcl?p=preview)

You cannot use `$scope.$emit` because your directives' scopes don't have parent/child relationship. You could refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402756/angularjs-emit-only-works-within-its-current-scope) for more information.

**Update:**

If your directives are not related and you need to have parent/child relationship, you could try custom transclusion:

```
app.directive('fold', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        foldName: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: 'fold.html',
      transclude:true,

      compile: function (element, attr, linker) {
          return {
           pre: function (scope, element, attr) {
             linker(scope, function(clone){ //bind the scope your self
                 element.children().eq(1).append(clone); // add to DOM
             });
           },
           post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {  
               scope.$on("foldplay",function(event,data){
                 alert(data);
               });
            }
          };
      }
    };
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZ08QzKch2Ykdj6d9wUs?p=preview) (click on the button and then click on the shown text)

Comment: Thanks but in my case, sometimes, sound-button has no parent fold...Moreover, the fold can be nested and the top one should also be awared that's why I need $emit.

Comment: @user2944669: I added 1 more solution with custom transclusion

Comment: Very smart ! Between your proposal and mine (leave everything in controller but cheat in the way I call emit $scope.$parent.$prevSibling), what would be the pros / cons ?

Comment: @user2944669: this is to change angular's default way of creating scope hierarchy. Sorry to say that I don't know why angular does that

Comment: Yes, I don't know why ng-transclude creates this sibling scope. Much of an annoyance than anything else !

Comment: @user2944669: I also don't see why angular does it. People usually expect that they have child/parent relationship.